# Optimal way to combine two vectors in vc++

Tags: algorithm, visual-c++, vector, logic

I am finding a better logic to combine 2 vectors.

```
vector_A[id][mark1];
vector_B[id][mark2];

vector_A: id = [300 , 502, 401 , 900 , 800 ,700 , 250 , 001] 
          mark1 = [55 , 50 , 30 , 28 , 25 , 11 , 04 , 03]

vector_B: id = [800 , 005 , 502 , 925 ,025 ,300 , 52] 
          mark2 = [75, 60 , 50 ,35 , 30 , 25 , 04]
```

combination rule is If same id find in two vectors add mark1 and mark2. If not just display.

```
vector_combined: id = [800 , 300 , 502 , 005 , 925 , 401] 
                 mark_combine = [100, 80 , 100 , 60 , 35 ,30]
```

Please help me with a optimal solution.

Comment: when you say "a better logic" you imply you already have a way to combine them. can you show it so that we can figure if something can be done better?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [this question of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449962/better-logic-to-combine-2-vectors) from a couple of hours ago which got an amazing 15 downvotes?

Comment: @Jean: Yes it is an exact dup, but it looks like the original is now closed and at -15 with little chance for an answer.  Yes the problem description is terrible, but given that s/he was upfront about tagging it as `homework` I'm inclined to give the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: Your question is stated very imprecisely -- for example, the word "display" doesn't make any sense.  It's OK for people whose first language isn't English to have spelling/grammar mistakes, but you need to get the meaning across, which you're not doing here.  Luckily it's possible to infer from your code snippets what you actually want to know.

Comment: The way I would ask this question is: "Given the following 4 vectors:" (followed by your 1st code snippet) "I want to create the following 2 vectors:" (followed by the 2nd code snippet) "That is, if a number appears in both `vector_A` and `vector_B`, then it should appear in `vector_C`, and the corresponding element of `mark_combine` should be the sum of the corresponding elements from `mark1` and `mark2`."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here on SO we're happy to assist people with *hints* for homework questions, provided they have been up-front about acknowledging the question as homework -- as you have been :)

As things are now, to find a match for a particular element in `vector_A`, you need to scan every element of `vector_B`.  So if there are m elements in `vector_A` and n elements in `vector_B`, this will take O(mn) time to find all matches -- quite slow.

Suppose we sort these two vectors, and reorder `mark1` and `mark2` accordingly as well.  What you now notice is that when looking for a particular element in `vector_B`, you can stop as soon as you get to an element that is too large -- since you know that all later elements must be even larger.  That will save some time.

In fact you can go one step further and look at just the 1st element of `vector_A` and `vector_B`.  Let's call these `a` and `b` respectively.  Now only one of 3 cases can occur:

1. `a < b`.  In this case, we can conclude that `a` cannot appear *anywhere* in `vector_B`, since all later elements will be at least as large as `b`, which is already too large.
2. `a > b`.  Similarly we can conclude that `b` cannot appear *anywhere* in `vector_A`, since all later elements will be at least as large as `a`, which is already too large.
3. `a = b`.  In that case, clearly this number appears in both vectors!

Bearing in mind that sorting takes just O(nlog n) time, this should give you a big hint for a faster algorithm.  If you need a bit more help understanding, leave a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your problem correctly... but, are you by any chance looking for [std::set_intersection](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/) ?

The algorithm requires your ranges to be sorted. So, sort them and feed them to `set_intersection`